# Python Dbus Error while installing through pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, dbus

```
python -m  pip install dbus-python
Collecting dbus-python
  Using cached dbus-python-1.2.16.tar.gz (576 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dbus-python, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dbus-python
    Running setup.py install for dbus-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\pure8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pure8\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zphzgd3p\\dbus-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pure8\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zphzgd3p\\dbus-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pure8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-l_6vpx3k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\pure8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Include\dbus-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\pure8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zphzgd3p\dbus-python\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    creating C:\Users\pure8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zphzgd3p\dbus-python\build
    creating C:\Users\pure8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zphzgd3p\dbus-python\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    error: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\pure8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pure8\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zphzgd3p\\dbus-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pure8\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zphzgd3p\\dbus-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pure8\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-l_6vpx3k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\pure8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Include\dbus-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

> every time I try to install dbus it gives me an error, I tried installing 32 bit and 64 bit of new python updates, and they are added to PATH, but that didn't help to install dbus. Dbus is required for notify2.

Comment: Run cmd as administrator and try.

Comment: The cmd gave the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had met the same problem.

Perhaps it's not recommended to use dbus-python on the Windows.

I just move the folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus` (Linux) to the Python2.7 folder (Windows).

And I can see the dbus in the VScode by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse(left).